# Can emacs running in two different windows on the same computer share the buffers?

Tags: emacs

I have connected a monitor to my laptop via VGA port to have extended screen space. 
As the screens are not of the same size and resolution,  increasing the size of the emacs window does not work effectively ( parts of the window get clipped from sides).

If I start two instances of `emacs`, i.e two windows of emacs, is there a way to access the same set of buffers in them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C-x 5 2` Create a new "Frame", Meaning a new windows in the classical sense. Both windows being part of the same Emacs share mostly everything

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved by starting emacs as a daemon and connecting it with `emacsclient -c`.  This method is convenient when you want to connect same emacs instance from terminal.